# Getting button image to stick to left side swift xcode

Tags: swift, user-interface, button

Currently trying to add a login with facebook button with xcode 7 beta. However, I have noticed that whenever I readjust the image's width, it seems to leave to left side which is where I want it to stay to the left margin. I am getting this image through the image option when I used the button. [image: When run on simulator and I click the facebook button the UI is terrible]

Comment: Do you use UIButton's image?

Comment: @pixyzehn I updated the question, have a look thx

Comment: Sure. I'll look that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same situation before. In that time, I adjust image inset in storyboard option.

Change image in Edge, and then adjust inset as you like.

[image]

But sometimes it doesn't work in my case(ex. the image size is so big). If so, you adjust the original image size.